# MySQL - CREATE FUNCTION ? MODIFIES SQL DATA?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, create-function

I am about to write a `CREATE FUNCTION` with **MySQL** and I am wondering, if `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` counts toward flag `MODIFIES SQL DATA`.
Function **does not modify any permanent table**, just temporary table, which it creates for optimization purpose.

Should I use flag `MODIFIES SQL DATA` or only `READS SQL DATA`?
What is a really **benefit** to use `MODIFIES SQL DATA` or `READS SQL DATA` flag anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now (MySQL 5.5) these characteristics serve only as an in-code documentation.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html

> Several characteristics provide information about the nature of data
>   use by the routine. In MySQL, these characteristics are advisory only.
>   The server does not use them to constrain what kinds of statements a
>   routine will be permitted to execute.

This is in contrast with `(NON)DETERMINISTIC` clause, which serves as a hint to optimizer whether the results of function can be cached.

Comment: :: Thanks! Mentioning `(NON)DETERMINISTIC` I am wondering, if such cache can be (somehow) cleared. In my case, database tables are modified once per month, so it would be nice to cache results and **optimize response time**, if there is some way, how to **clear cache**, when the update of database tables is done. Any advice?

Comment: @stackoverflow: Look up query cache http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html . Basically it's refreshed whenever data in underlying tables is updated.